# Super simple Keras Sequence doesn't work when serving simple array data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Below is a simple XOR solver, with and without using a Sequence for training data.
Just using regular arrays works, but when using a Sequence to serve the same data, it doesn't work.
I don't understand the error message, which is in the comment on the last line.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np 

X = np.array([ [0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1] ])
y = np.array([ [0], [1], [1], [0] ])

model = Sequential()
model.add( Dense(8,input_dim=2) )
model.add( Activation('tanh') )
model.add( Dense(1) )
model.add( Activation('sigmoid') )

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1)
model.compile( loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd )

# this works
model.fit( X, y, verbose=2, batch_size=1, epochs=500 )

# afaikt, this following is the same thing, but it doesn't work!

from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence

class MySequence( Sequence ) :
    def __len__( self ) :
        return len(X)
    def __getitem__( self, index ) :
        # batch size 1 of tuple X,y
        return [( X[index], y[index] )]

model.fit( MySequence(), batch_size=1 )
# ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors.
# Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_1:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int32>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things happen in `model.fit`, including Keras creating a dataset, and adding a batch dimension. Since you created a new kind of dataset I'm afraid that's something you'll have to do yourself. It will work if you change the `return` statement to this:

```
return X[index][None, ...], y[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the order wrong. You shout not have a batch of 1 tuple `(features, labels)`, but 1 tuple of `(batched features, batched labels)`

```
return [X[index]], [y[index]]
```

Comment: was really torn over which of these two answers to accept; the other one had a code change that actually worked, but this one explained better what my misunderstanding was